# Proper nullable type checking in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, nullable

Ok, my actual problem was this: I was implementing an `IList<T>`. When I got to `CopyTo(Array array, int index)`, this was my solution:

```
void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
{
    // Bounds checking, etc here.
    if (!(array.GetValue(0) is T))
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot cast to this type of Array.");
    // Handle copying here.
}
```

This worked in my original code, and still works. But it has a small flaw, which wasn't exposed till I started building tests for it, specifically this one:

```
public void CopyToObjectArray()
{
    ICollection coll = (ICollection)_list;
    string[] testArray = new string[6];

    coll.CopyTo(testArray, 2);
}
```

Now, this test should pass. It throws the `ArgumentException` about not being able to cast. Why? `array[0] == null`. The `is` keyword always returns false when checking a variable that is set to `null`. Now, this is handy for all sorts of reasons, including avoiding null dereferences, etc. What I finally came up with for my type checking was this:

```
try
{
    T test = (T)array.GetValue(0);
}
catch (InvalidCastException ex)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Cannot cast to this type of Array.", ex);
}
```

This isn't exactly elegant, but it works... Is there a better way though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to be sure is with reflection, but 90% of the time you can avoid the cost of that by using `array is T[]`.  Most people are going to pass a properly typed array in, so that will do.  But, you should always provide the code to do the reflection check as well, just in case.  Here's what my general boiler-plate looks like (note: I wrote this here, from memory, so this might not compile, but it should give the basic idea):

```
class MyCollection : ICollection<T> {
   void ICollection<T>.CopyTo(T[] array, int index) {
       // Bounds checking, etc here.
       CopyToImpl(array, index);
   }
   void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index) {
       // Bounds checking, etc here.
       if (array is T[]) { // quick, avoids reflection, but only works if array is typed as exactly T[]
           CopyToImpl((T[])localArray, index);
       } else {
           Type elementType = array.GetType().GetElementType();
           if (!elementType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) && !typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(elementType)) {
               throw new Exception();
           }
           CopyToImpl((object[])array, index);
       }
   }
   private void CopyToImpl(object[] array, int index) {
       // array will always have a valid type by this point, and the bounds will be checked
       // Handle the copying here
   }
}
```

**EDIT**: Ok, forgot to point something out.  A couple answers naively used what, in this code, reads as `element.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` only.  You *should* also allow `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(elementType)`, as the BCL does, in case a developer knows that all of the values in this specific `ICollection` are actually of a type `S` derived from `T`, and passes an array of type `S[]`

Comment: How do you suggest handling the case where not all elements are of a type S, and a InvalidCastException gets thrown? User beware?

Comment: That's the way the BCL does it.

Comment: The "is" keyword in C# is a reflection call. So you're not saving much by going the long way around the track. Just cut right to the chase and do the IsAssignableFrom.

Comment: @just in case: Actually in this case "is" is implemented via the "isinst" CIL instruction (ECMA-225 Partition III, Section 4.6).  While technically the JIT is allowed to call reflection to implement it, both MS-CLR and Mono have _very_ efficient inline code for it (it also runs every time you unbox)

Answer (score 4):

There is a method on Type specifically for this, try:

```
if(!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(array.GetElementType()))
```

Comment: Using reflection is surely going to be more expensive than just going for the invalid cast.

Comment: +1 for effort, and a solution that works. Performance wise though, I think I have to side with ffpf, Reflection is probably taking the long route around.

Comment: Thinking about it (and having a mental slap), I think this is probably the only way to do this properly.

Comment: As a single conditional statement anyway, yeah.

Comment: It would only be faster to use the try / catch if the cast happened to be correct. If you have an exception thrown and you catch it here then you are going to see a drastic performance hit vs. an extremely minor one with reflection. Don't be afraid of reflection, it is still pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` uses this:

```
try
{
    Array.Copy(this._items, 0, array, index, this.Count);
}
catch (ArrayTypeMismatchException)
{
  //throw exception...
}
```

Comment: Ugly. I would rather it just bubble up the exception.

Comment: List<T> throws an ArgumentException, which *is* more appropriate

Comment: Since you're taking the effort though, I'd probably pass the ArrayTypeMismatch as an inner exception though.

Comment: List<T> has T already... so it's pretty easy to make sure you have the right type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little test of try / catch vs. reflection:

```
object[] obj = new object[] { };
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Try/Catch: " + (end - start).TotalSeconds.ToString());

start = DateTime.Now;

for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
{
    bool assignable = typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType().GetElementType());
}
end = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("IsAssignableFrom: " + (end - start).TotalSeconds.ToString());
```

The resulting output in Release mode is:

```
Try/Catch: 1.7501001
IsAssignableFrom: 0
```

In debug mode:

```
Try/Catch: 1.8171039
IsAssignableFrom: 0.0010001
```

Conclusion, just do the reflection check. It's worth it.

Comment: You always make that assumption when calculating performance.